# How to Pass High Resolution from GRUB2 to FreeBSD?

Tags: boot, freebsd, grub2, console, resolution

I boot FreeBSD-10-RELEASE from GRUB2. I have set up the GRUB2 boot menu to display very nicely at my laptop's max resolution of 1024x768x32. I know it's possible to pass this resolution to the boot loader with the `gfxpayload` command but it's not working.

Within FreeBSD itself I've configured the console to display at this resolution but this doesn't kick in until about midway through the boot device scan. What happens is that after I select my FreeBSD menu entry in GRUB2, the FreeBSD boot loader takes over with the usual FreeBSD boot menu displayed in ugly 640x480 resolution.

I've followed every direction I could find that would claim to pass the GRUB2 resolution on but nothing works. Is it possible this function does not work with FreeBSD (because installing and configuring GRUB2 in FreeBSD has been problematic for me from the start) or is there some other configuration specific to FreeBSD?

Even though this is not necessary in terms of functionality, it would be nice to have this last little thing after I finally managed to get everything else on my system working great. This would be a nice cherry on top!

Comment: Two things to consider: first- is that until you system have your graphic card probed you are stuck with the ugly res. second- your resolution at boot is only related to framebufer. I don't know if freebsd 10 supports vesa framebuffer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is even possible, but try adding `vesa_load="YES"` to your `loader.conf` and see how that goes.

Also, why are you chainloading?